# Spring Data Rest - How to remove an element from a Page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I have the following REST controller method in my project

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "applications", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<?> getApplications(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Application.class) Predicate predicate,
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler, Pageable page) {

    Page<ApplicationProjection> applications = appRepo.findAll(predicate, page).
            map(item -> projectionFactory.createProjection(ApplicationProjection.class, item));

    return new ResponseEntity<>(pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(applications), HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Now I want to remove some elements of the Page based on a condition. How do I implement in Spring Data Rest?

Comment: Your page probably has a certain size. If you remove some elements from it, you may end up with an uncomplete page, client-side. Can't you use your Query to exclude the elements you want to exclude?

Comment: Do you mean QueryDSL?

Comment: Here, you are calling a `findAll` method that doesn't use any criteria and selects all your entities. Why can't you define another method in your repository (with @Query) and use the required criterias to exclude some entities?

Comment: I am using QueryDSL Predicate so I can filter it the results dynamically based on queryParams. Now the queryParams are sent by user when invoking the enpoint but I want add an extra criteria to the predicate but I am not sure how to implement it

Comment: If I use a findAll method with query I cant use QueryDSL

Comment: This looks like a [x y problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Xy) 
 to me. I suggest you learn how to add a criteria to your predicate instead of trying to remove elements from your Page.

Comment: I am familiar with predicates but in this scenario I am not able to modify it.

Answer (score 9):

You can't directly remove elements from a Page. What you can do is, get the content from the page, that will be a list and then remove the the element from the list according to your condition , then create a new Page with the modified list and size.

```
Page<ApplicationProjection> applications = appRepo.findAll(predicate, page).
                    map(item -> projectionFactory.createProjection(ApplicationProjection.class, item));

List<ApplicationProjection> appList = applications.getContent();
// logic to remove the elements as per your condition modifiedAppList
// create a new Page with the modified list and size
Page<ApplicationProjection> newApplicationsPage = new PageImpl<>(modifiedAppList, PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize),modifiedAppList.size());
```

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse. I will definitely check this out

Comment: @Charlie Accept the answer maybe? ;)

Comment: The problem with this is that new page won't have any of pagination metadata, so will misreport total numbers of pages/elements, is-last-page etc.