# Java Spring doesn't return DTO objects if null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, microservices, dto

I have a Java implementation Override method which returns DTO object results from 2 microservices depending on entered parameters.

I am able to get filtered search results however where the 2nd service conditions were not met I receive 'null' I would want to achieve a results where null objects are not returned whatsoever.How am I able to return results which meet all specified parameters?

Below I have provided screenshot of response I receive using "Swagger" and the code snipped which does all the magic.

Would I require to use ObjectMapper or something like `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`, however can I use it within service implantation and with DTO objects?

Any further suggestions or idea bouncing would be appreciated.

I have further build on my previous question [Java pass variable into mapped DTO method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304182/java-pass-variable-into-mapped-dto-method)

Swagger response:

[image]

Code snippet:

```
    @Override
public Page<ProfileCreditDTO> findProfileBySelectedParameters(String username, Integer gender, Integer profileType, Integer orientation, Boolean online, Double profileCredit, Integer creditMode, Double creditTotal, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Profile> searchData= profileRepository.findByAllParameters(username, gender, profileType, orientation, online, pageable);
    Page<ProfileCreditDTO> searchProfileData=null;
    if(searchData != null)
        searchProfileData = searchData.map(x -> this.convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO(x, profileCredit, creditMode, creditTotal));
    return searchProfileData;
}


public ProfileCreditDTO convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO(final Profile theProfile, Double profileCredit, Integer creditMode, Double creditTotal)  {
    if(theProfile == null)
        return null;
    ProfileCreditDTO theDTO= new ProfileCreditDTO();
    theDTO.setProfile(theProfile);
    CreditDTO theCreditDto = profileCreditClient.findClientByProfileId(theProfile.getId(), profileCredit, creditMode, creditTotal);
    log.error(String.valueOf(theCreditDto));
    if (theCreditDto != null)
        theDTO.setCredit(theCreditDto);
    else {
        return null;
    }

    return theDTO;
}
```

**Updated**

I have tried adding `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` into ProfileCredit DTO still nothing, also have added same thing into CreditDTO.

ProfileCredit DTO:

```
 @Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ProfileCreditDTO {
    // profile fields
    private Long profileId;
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50)
    private String username;
    private Integer gender;
    private Integer profileType;
    private Integer orientation;
    private boolean online;


    // Credit fields
    private Long creditId;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private Double profileCredit;  //X
    private Integer creditMode;
    private Integer creditCheck;
private Double creditTotal;

/**
 * set the profile derived data
 * @param profile
 */
public void setProfile(final Profile profile){
    this.setProfileId(profile.getId());
    this.setUsername(profile.getUsername());
    this.setGender(profile.getGender());
    this.setProfileType(profile.getProfileType());
    this.setOrientation(profile.getOrientation());
    this.setOnline(profile.isOnline());
}

/**
 * Set the credit aspect
 * @param credit
 */
public void setCredit(final CreditDTO credit){
    this.setCreditId(credit.getId());
    this.setProfileId(credit.getProfileId());
    this.setProfileCredit(credit.getProfileCredit());
    this.setCreditMode(credit.getCreditMode());
    this.setCreditTotal(credit.getCreditTotal());

}
```

When I don't specify `return null;` within implementation, the response looks like this. As you can see all objects gets returned which meets condition 1 but where condition 2 is not met empty object fields are returned.

[image]

Comment: as you said just add @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) at the DTO level.

Comment: @dassum adding  `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` does nothing

Comment: can you share your DTO? Where did you put @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)?

Comment: @Lemmy I have updated the question

Comment: `but where condition 2 is not met empty object fields are returned.` What is condition 2? There are no empty objects here.

Comment: fields "creditId" and after are from different microservice. Within my controller (which as of yet are not displayed) contains optional fields, where you are able to provide parameters on which filtered result will be given. So if you enter parameters creditMode(profileCredit) 0 and username(profile) you should be returned data depending on what you requested @ChristopherSchneider

Comment: `if (theCreditDto != null)
            theDTO.setCredit(theCreditDto);
        else if (theCreditDto == null){
            theDTO = null;
        }` To get null I added this @ChristopherSchneider

Comment: Again, there are no empty objects here. There are `int` values that are zero, if that's what you're talking about. `int` is not an object. `0` is the default value on an `int`. If these values are nullable, they need to be `Integer`.

Comment: I have updated from abstract `double` and primitive `int` to `Double` and `Integer`, now those fields don't show up whatsoever if they don't meet the condition. Well spotted @ChristopherSchneider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "objects" which are elements can't be directly removed from a Page. What you can do is, get the content from the page, that will be a list and then remove the the element from the list according to your condition , then create a new Page with the data fields required for a Page.

Instead of

```
    @Override
public Page<ProfileCreditDTO> findProfileBySelectedParameters(String username, Integer gender, Integer profileType, Integer orientation, Boolean online, Double profileCredit, Integer creditMode, Double creditTotal, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Profile> searchData= profileRepository.findByAllParameters(username, gender, profileType, orientation, online, pageable);
    Page<ProfileCreditDTO> searchProfileData=null;
    if(searchData != null)
        searchProfileData = searchData.map(x -> this.convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO(x, profileCredit, creditMode, creditTotal));
    return searchProfileData;
}
```

try

```
   @Override
public Page<ProfileCreditDTO> findProfileBySelectedParameters(String username, Integer gender, Integer profileType, Integer orientation, Boolean online, Double profileCredit, Integer creditMode, Double creditTotal, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Profile> searchData= profileRepository.findByAllParameters(username, gender, profileType, orientation, online, pageable);
    Page<ProfileCreditDTO> searchProfileData=null;
    if(searchData != null)
        searchProfileData = searchData.map(x -> this.convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO(x, profileCredit, creditMode, creditTotal));

    List modifiedAppList = searchProfileData.getContent().stream().filter(v -> v !=null).collect(Collectors.toList()); //Will filter your search result and put it into a list

    Page<ProfileCreditDTO> filteredList = new PageImpl<>(modifiedAppList, new PageRequest(0, searchProfileData.getSize()), searchProfileData.getTotalElements()); //Will put your filtered list back into page

    return  filteredList; //Returns filtered result

}
```

Got the answer for this question from [Spring Data Rest - How to remove an element from a Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401929/spring-data-rest-how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-page) only amended the code and bit of the wording, as answer was already spot on ;)

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

**add this**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```